# Create a dictionary based on fields copied from a Google sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hardcoded a database containing personnel into one of my files because I don't know if there's a better way of doing this.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
autocompleteList2 = {
' ': [' ', ' '],   #so my first input value will be blank 
'James': ['James@gmail.com', '555-555-5555'],
```

I copied a few columns containing similar data from a Google sheet. There's a ton of data. How can I quickly copy/paste this data and have it join my current dictionary? In other words, I want to copy/paste column 1 containing all first names, column 2 containing e-mail addresses, etc, and have it end up like shown above.

The second part of my question: Is this the best way to do it? Would it be better to have my program query the Google sheet for new data? I'm worried that it'll just cause issues with having to connect and authenticate all the time.

Comment: How often do you need the dictionary to be updated? Could you download the sheet as a csv file yourself?

Comment: Not often at all. Perhaps once a month... I suppose I'd be able to update my code and push it to the guys using my program. 
Yes it seems I can download as .csv. How does this help me, though? Can I somehow use the .csv as a dictionary? Or can I convert the .csv into dictionary format to put into my code?

Comment: You can download the sheet as a csv file, and then read each line into a dictionary with a for loop. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use google's [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) to do what you want. But if you're worried about having to connect and authenticate all the time and just want something quick and dirty just export the google sheet as a csv then do something like this:

```py
import csv

autocompletelist2 = {' ': [' ', ' ']}
with open('data.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        autocompletelist2[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2]]
```

The result `autocompletelist2` will be the dictionary output that you want:

```py
{
    ' ': [' ', ' '],
    'James': ['James@gmail.com', '555-555-5555'], 
    'Mike': ['Mike@gmail.com', '888-888-8888'] #...and so on...
}
```

Comment: if you have more columns than specified in your question, as per @Kyle Roth's answer you can do `autocompletelist2[row[0]] = row[1:]` instead

Answer (score 0):

If (as you mention in the comments) it's reasonable to periodically download the Google Sheet as it's updated, the easiest solution might be to download it as a csv (comma-separated value) file and read it into a dictionary like this:

```
autocompleteList2 = {}
with open('googlesheet.csv') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        items = line.split(',')
        autocomleteList2[items[0]] = items[1:]
```

The drawback is that this would have to read the csv file every time you wanted to use the dictionary. An alternative is to create a pickle of the dictionary:

```
import pickle

autocompleteList2 = {}
with open('googlesheet.csv') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        items = line.split(',')
        autocomleteList2[items[0]] = items[1:]

with open('autocompleteList2.pkl', 'wb+') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(autocompleteList2, outfile)
```

This creates a file called 'autocompleteList2.pkl', which can then be loaded any time by doing the following:

```
import pickle

with open('autocompleteList2.pkl', 'wb+') as infile:
    autocompleteList2 = pickle.load(infile)
```

Be careful with emailing `.pkl` files around though; they're [known to be insecure](https://michael-rushanan.blogspot.com/2012/10/why-python-pickle-is-insecure.html). Send the csv file and the code to create the pickle file, and have each user create the pickle on their own machine.

Comment: Interesting! Why bother with pickle format though? reading the .csv seems to work well.

Comment: Regardless, it's interesting to know about it! Thank you!